# How to change theme using multi provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm using Multiprovider in app, one of those providers is GlobalProvider that contains info regarding app wide state, I want to use that provider to switch brightness of theme. But I'm getting an error when I'm trying to run the attached code.

```
void main() => runApp(NextActionApp());

class NextActionApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextActionApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<GlobalBloc>.value(
          value: GlobalBloc(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'App',
        home: InboxPage(),
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
          brightness: Provider.of<GlobalBloc>(context).isDarkModeEnabled
              ? Brightness.dark
              : Brightness.light,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved it with the `builder` Method of `MultiProvider`.
The part

```
builder: (context, child) {
   return  MaterialApp ...
}
```

did the trick.

Here an complete example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(create: (context) => ThemeNotifier()),
        ],
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
              //  light theme settings
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
            ),
            darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(
                // dark theme settings
                ),
            themeMode: Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context).themeMode,
            home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in the next way:

```
void main() async {


final prefs = new PreferenciasUsuario();
  await prefs.initPrefs();
  setupLocator();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(
      create: (_) => ThemeProvider(isLightTheme: true),
    ),


    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final prefs = new PreferenciasUsuario();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(
      create: ( BuildContext context ) => ThemeProvider(isLightTheme: true),
      child: CustomeProvider(
        child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(builder: ( context, model, __ ){
          return new MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Material App',
            initialRoute: prefs.isLogged?'home':'login',
            routes: {
              'login'   : ( BuildContext context ) => LoginPage(),
              'home'    : ( BuildContext context ) => HomePage(),
              'config'  : ( BuildContext context ) => ConfiguracionesPage(),
            },
            theme: model.getThemeData
          );
        })
      )

    );
  }
}
```